# How to debug Spring Boot with Netbeans via Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

After fiddling around for way too long till I got proper debuging setup in Netbeans 8.2 with Spring Boot 1.4.3 I figured I write down my findings as Q&A for others.

The problem is that the default configuration for Netbeans fails to properly launch Spring in debug mode and when you search the internet you only find the outdated information in the Spring docs that won't work.

The solution is simple if you know how. Please find the correct setup instructions below.

Comment: It works better with Netbeans 11.2 or 11.3 especially if you are using SpringBoot and maven. Very easy to switch

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tested and works with Netbeans 8.2 and Spring-Boot 1.4.3:

First of all make sure you have the Spring Maven plugin included (this should be already included when making a new Netbeans Spring project):

```
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

Also it is a good idea to include the Spring Devtools like this:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Now navigate to your project settings -> Actions -> Debug project and set the following:

[image]

Execute goals:

```
spring-boot:run
```

Set properties:

```
run.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}
jpda.listen=true
```

Now run your application via the usual debug button and Spring should properly connect to the JVM debugger.

#### Spring Boot 2.x

To enable Netbeans debugging for a Spring Boot 2.x project (and more specifically version 2.x of the spring-boot-maven-plugin) the procedure is exactly the same, except the `run.jvmArguments` property name has changed to `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`:

```
spring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}
jpda.listen=true
```

Comment: It's doesn't work for me...
When I run in debug mode the debug-output print "JPDA Listening Start..." and nothing happings...
You have any idea what's happing?

Comment: This works OK, except "step into" behaves more like "step over" -- can't find a way to actually step into anything :(

Comment: I want to point out also that you actually you don't need spring-boot-maven-plugin if you are using spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: Since version 2.0.0.M3 of the spring-boot-maven-plugin, you need to change `run.jvmArguments` to `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/4510be0f8f1af1f907d329fcf1bc7b4d00772ef2

Comment: For some reason the debugger does not stop at breakpoints. I'm using spring boot v 2.1 & netbeans 11. any tips?

Comment: Works with Spring Boot 2.1.6 and Netbeans 12.

Answer (score 4):

Testing NetBeans 8.2 and Spring Boot 2.0.1, I was not able to make things work following [@TwoThe's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633184/196844). First, I encountered an issue where all I saw was "JPDA Listening Start..." in the output window. To resolve that problem, I added [Spring Devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) as an optional dependency. Second, even though debugging appeared to be running okay, the "Debugging" window, which normally displays the list of active threads, was empty and breakpoints that I set were not triggered. Third, attempting to stop the debugging session by pressing the red "Finish Debugger Session" button would not stop the Tomcat server.

Instead of changing the execute goals to "spring-boot:run", I found that it was sufficient to use the default "Debug project" action execute goals:

```
process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
```

.. and properties:

```
exec.args=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}
exec.executable=java
jpda.listen=true
```

(As a sidenote, debugging as a regular Java application is apparently the recommended approach to debugging Spring Boot applications in Eclipse; see [How to debug Spring Boot application with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24113939/196844))

One helpful tip is that if you want to debug using a certain Spring Boot profile, say "debug", you can prepend "-Dspring.profiles.active=debug " to the "exec.args" property. See also: [Spring boot running a fully executable JAR and specify -D properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33855713/196844)

Comment: Using this config gives me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors. Maybe I need explicitly specify classpath?

Comment: @zygimantus Which class is not found? I have now added the default properties. Maybe try those.

Comment: Well those classes are generated by my project during Maven generate phase. I wonder why this issue came up for me...

Comment: It works better with Netbeans 11.2 or 11.3 especially if you are using SpringBoot and maven. Very easy to switch

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tested on NetBeans9

Action: Add any name
Set Properties: select Add> button, select Debug Maven Build
And debug as always -> IDE debug button

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having the problem after applying all above mentioned fixes, remove all your breakpoints and try again.
Window -> Debugging -> Breakpoints -> Delete All Breakpoints

Comment: the difference was that it was pointing to debug from run.jvmArguments and the key was spring-boot.run.jvmArguments

Answer (score 0):

## POW

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

buld

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                  <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                  </goals>
                                </execution>
                              </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

## Debug Project

- **Excute Goals** : package
- **Set Properties**:netbeans.deploy.debugmode=true netbeans.deploy=true

## Change

- **Excute Goals** : spring-boot:run
- **Set Properties**: spring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}
  jpda.listen=true

and Netbeans Press debug project -- not navigator--> spring-boo-run ... What was the difference? spring-boot.run.jvmArguments: