# How to resolve placeholder when run Spring based application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file, property-placeholder

Collegues, i have java based Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.abc.dirint"})
@PropertySource("classpath:/settings/${env}/dir.properties")
@EnableScheduling
public class DirConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DirConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

     @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }


        /*Beans follow...*/ 

        }
```

When i execute `mvn clean package -Denv=dev` it run tests and build project without any error.

Now i would like to run compiled jar. 
I execute `java -jar dir-integration-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar -Denv=dev` and the program fails (this is expected) with th next stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.abc.dirint.DirConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in string value "classpath:/settings/${env}/dir.properties"
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
```

Wnen i run `$ java -jar dir-integration-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar --env=dev` the result is next:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.abc.dirint.DirConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in string value "classpath:/settings/${env}/dir.properties"
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
        at com.abc.dirint.AdApp.main(AdApp.java:19) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in string value "classpath:/settings/${env}/dir.properties"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:571)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:379)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:
```

What should I do to receive properties from the specified properties file during app running?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855713/spring-boot-running-a-fully-executable-jar-and-specify-d-properties

Comment: Try running as:   java -Denv=dev -jar dir-integration-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `java -h`

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
...
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
```

Therefore the correct command to run your jar with system property provided should be `java -Denv=dev -jar dir-integration-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` instead

---

And, you should be aware that, using `mvn ... -Denv=dev` vs `java -Denv=dev ...` is two totally different thing.

With `mvn`, placeholder replacement happens in **compile time**, which means the final jar will contains `@PropertySource("classpath:/settings/dev/dir.properties")`

However, your 2nd approach is to keep the placeholder in compiled class, and rely on Spring to perform the replace in **runtime**